# Symbol for cardinal numbers

Tags: symbols

There is a number symbol `#` so that when you put it in front of a number, it tells that the number is an ordinal number. E.g., `#6` means "number 6".

Is there a symbol like that for cardinal numbers? E.g., if put in front of `23`, it should mean "23 in total" or "23 counts".

---

The following is my use case. It may not be necessary to understand my question.

I have a lot of numbers displayed aside of tags. Some tags have ordinal numbers and others have cardinal numbers. I want to make them distinguishable between ordinal or cardinal. I did to things: (i) write the cardinal number before the tag whereas write the ordinal number after the tag, (ii) put the number symbol `#` in front of an ordinal number. Examples are like this:

Example of a tag with ordinary number

```
[Foo #1] [Foo #2] ... [Foo #23]
[Bar #1] [Bar #2] ... [Bar #17]
```

Example of a tag with cardinal number

```
[23 Foo] [17 Bar]
```

I want to put some symbol in front of these cardinal numbers.

Comment: I think "[Foo x23] [Bar x17]", ie a small x to imply "times" is what is generally used. **IF** I understood correctly.

Comment: @VilleNiemi That can be an answer.

Comment: [23x Foo] [17x Bar] might also work.

Comment: Can you give some more context to the examples? Symbols like à or á are also used for cardinal numbers.

Comment: Also are different languages/cultures a concern? Because there might be other ways or symbols for presenting these numbers.

Comment: The mathematical symbol for cardinality of the set _A_ is |A| (that is, wrapping the set name in vertical pipes). Still, I wouldn’t expect that to be reasonably well understood by typical users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to do this is by **representing the count** rather than have a symbol for cardinal numbers.  Some ways of doing this are:

- Foo x23
- Foo (23)
- 23 Foo(s)

Personally I like the visual clarity of `Foo (23)` but you're probably safer going with `Foo x23`

Answer (score 0):

I think "n=" might work, as borrowed from how sample sizes are usually abbreviated when statistical tests/results are presented.

Also "Σ=" might work although for a sum to be proper, people might require of it that the values summed are capable of taking on values other than just 1. Technically though, of course, a count just is a sum, too.